# Convert factor of minutes:seconds:miliseconds to miliseconds

Tags: r, time, lubridate

I have a column of times which exist as factors in a column in the following format `1:38.109` (i.e. 1 minute, 38 seconds, and 109 milliseconds)

How can I convert this to a single continuous variable (i.e. 98109 milliseconds) in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)

test <- data.frame(time_fac = c("1:38.109", "2:01.302", "0:23.12", "0:01"))
test$time_ms = as.numeric(lubridate::ms(as.character(test$time_fac)))*1000
```

`as.character` is used to convert the factor variable, `time_fac`, to character before the `lubridate::ms` gets the time in time format, which is converted to numeric (in seconds) and multiplied by 1000 to get time in milliseconds.

```
> test
  time_fac time_ms
1 1:38.109   98109
2 2:01.302  121302
3  0:23.12   23120
4     0:01    1000
```